# I called reduce on an array of strings. Why does this result in a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a number and I want to find the sum of the square of each digit. I started by turning it into a string, splitting it to get an array of strings representing each digit, and then used reduce to find the sum of the squares. I got the correct result with the code below, but I'm confused as to why it works. The Math.pow() would convert the digit to a number, but if you add it to a string, wouldn't it just concatenate them and produce a string? Like if I did '1' + Math.pow('2',2), I would expect '14'.

```js
let num = 19

const result = num.toString().split('').reduce(function(sum, curr) {
    return sum + Math.pow(curr, 2);
}, 0)

console.log(result);
```

And the code above produces 82 (which is what I want) but I don't know why it works.

Comment: `1^2 + 9^2 = 1 + 81 = 82`

Comment: `sum` is a number, and `Math.pow` returns a number. There is no string operand to your `+` operator. You would see the behaviour you expect if you used `'0'` as the initial value for `sum` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument passed to `reduce` will be the accumulator's initial value. Here, you passed 0:

```
num.toString().split('').reduce(function(sum, curr) {
    return sum + Math.pow(curr, 2);
}, 0)
// ^
```

So the value of `sum` in the first iteration is a number. You then add a number to it, which results in *another* number, which becomes the accumulator in the next iteration - and so on, until the end. The accumulator is always a number.

If you *hadn't* specified an initial value, the first value of the accumulator would be the first item in the array (the character `'1'`), and everything would have been *concatenated* rather than added:

```js
let num = 19

const result = num.toString().split('').reduce(function(sum, curr) {
    return sum + Math.pow(curr, 2);
})
console.log(result);
```

The result is `'181'` because `'1' + 81 === '181'`.

Comment: But my array is ['1', '9']. So in the first iteration, aren't I adding 0 + '1'? Which should coerce the sum to '1'?

Comment: `Math.pow` returns a number. In the first iteration, `return sum + Math.pow(curr, 2);` resolves to `return 0 + Math.pow('1', 2);` -> `return 0 + 1;` -> `return 1`.

Comment: OHH wait I see what's going on now. Never mind! Thank you